# Unable to install derivitive of sqlite

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

[image: Why am I getting "Permission denied"?]

Why am I getting "Permission denied"?

Comment: For future reference, it'd be a lot more helpful (and quicker) if you posted a simple text log of your session, not a screengrab. Also, showing the commands you used to get the result would also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you used `make install` instead of `sudo make install` - try using sudo instead.